# os.listdir() skips a file in a list

Tags: python, directory

My program currently gets a list of files from a directory and is supposed to move and rename them to another directory. Instead, it does file0 and file2, skipping file1. Here's my code:

```
files = glob.glob("oldfiles/*")
print("Length ==", len(files))
print(files)

# Beginning files are... atext0.txt, atext1.txt, atext2.txt

for file in range(len(files) - 1): # I have to subtract one due to it skipping a file
    newname = "ztext" + str(file) + ".txt"

    redundantname = os.listdir("oldfiles")[file]
    print(file)
    print(redundantname)

    shutil.move("oldfiles/" + redundantname, "newfiles/" + newname)
```

Output:

```
Length == 3
['oldfiles\\atext0.txt', 'oldfiles\\atext1.txt', 'oldfiles\\atext2.txt']
0
atext0.txt
1
atext2.txt
```

The files are renamed to ztext0 and 1.txt, but the original atext1.txt is left behind.

Comment: Could you explain why you subtract one i.e. `for file in range(len(files) - 1)`.  This is obviously why a file is left behind.

Comment: It skips from the first file to the third, leaving out the second. To stop it from outputting an IndexError I subtracted one.

Comment: It's not clear why you would get an IndexError without subtracting 1.   I didn't when I tried to replicate what you're doing.  But, subtracting 1 left out one of the files which is the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just iterate through `os.listdir("oldfiles")` ?

```
i=0
for file in os.listdit("oldfiles"):
    i+=1
    ...
```

and then you use `i` instead of the `file` variable that you use now